# Can't share global variable value between jobs in gitlab ci yaml file

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build an application using GitLab CI.

The name of the generated file is depending on the time, in this format

> DEV_APP_yyyyMMddhhmm

(example: `DEV_APP_201810221340`, corresponding to the date of today 2018/10/22 13h40).

How can I store this name in a global variable inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest
image: docker:latest
services:
- docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci
#   TIME: ""
#  BRANCH: ""
#  REC_BUILD_NAME: ""
  TIME: "timex"
  BRANCH: "branchx"
  DEV_BUILD_NAME: "DEV_APP_x"

stages:
- preparation
- build
- package
- deploy
- manual_rec_build
- manual_rec_package

job_preparation:
  stage: preparation
  script:
  - echo ${TIME}
  - export TIME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
  - "BRANCH=$(echo $CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG | sed 's/[^[[:alnum:]]/_/g')"
  - "DEV_BUILD_NAME=DEV_APP_${BRANCH}_${TIME}"
  - echo ${TIME}

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo ${TIME}
  - "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
paths:
    - target/*.jar
  only:
  - merge-requests
  - /^feature\/sprint.*$/
  - /^DEV_.*$/
#  when: manual


docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
  - echo ${TIME}
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/mourad.sellam/actuator-simple .
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - docker push registry.gitlab.com/mourad.sellam/actuator-simple
  only:
  - merge-requests
  - /^feature\/sprint.*$/
  - /^DEV_.*$/
  when: manual

    k8s-deploy-production:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo ${TIME}
  - echo "$GOOGLE_KEY" > key.json
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
  - gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-c
  - gcloud config set project actuator-sample
  - gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials actuator-example
  - kubectl delete secret registry.gitlab.com
  - kubectl create secret docker-registry registry.gitlab.com --docker-server=https://registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=myUserName--docker-password=$REGISTRY_PASSWD --docker-email=myEmail@gmail.com
  - kubectl apply -f deployment.yml --namespace=production
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.production.com
  when: manual

job_manual_rec_build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: manual_rec_build
  script:
  - echo ${TIME}
  - "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.jar
  when: manual
    #   allow_failure: false

job_manual_rec_package:
  stage: manual_rec_package
  variables:
  script:
    - echo ${TIME}
  - echo ${DEV_BUILD_NAME}
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/mourad.sellam/actuator-simple:${DEV_BUILD_NAME} .
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
- docker push registry.gitlab.com/mourad.sellam/actuator-simple
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.jar
  when: on_success
  #test 1
```

When I call

```
echo ${TIME}
```

It displays "timex".

[echo faild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytQAc.png)

Could you tell me how to store a global variable and set it in each job?

Comment: I couldn't pass variables this way either. I manually trigger through API using curl request and send variables through that. This works but you will not get that cool pipeline graph thats all

Comment: This is still an issue in 2020...

Answer (score 66):

Check if [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#inherit-environment-variables-from-other-jobs) could help in your case:

> ### Inherit environment variables from other jobs
>
> **Passing environment variables (or other data) between CI jobs is now possible**.
>
> By using the `dependencies` keyword (or `needs` keyword for DAG pipelines), a job can inherit variables from other jobs if they are sourced with `dotenv` report artifacts.
>
> This offers a more graceful approach for updating variables between jobs compared to artifacts or passing files.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22638).

> You can inherit environment variables from dependent jobs.
>
> This feature makes use of the [`artifacts:reports:dotenv`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) report feature.
>
> Example with [`dependencies`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies) keyword.
>
> ```
> build:
>   stage: build
>   script:
>     - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
>   artifacts:
>     reports:
>       dotenv: build.env
>
> deploy:
>   stage: deploy
>   script:
>     - echo $BUILD_VERSION # => hello
>   dependencies:
>     - build
> ```
>
> Example with the [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifact-downloads-with-needs) keyword:
>
> ```
> build:
>   stage: build
>   script:
>     - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
>   artifacts:
>     reports:
>       dotenv: build.env
>
> deploy:
>   stage: deploy
>   script:
>     - echo $BUILD_VERSION # => hello
>   needs:
>     - job: build
>       artifacts: true
> ```

---

Caveat: the "[Pass dotenv variables created in a job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project+pipeline#pass-dotenv-variables-created-in-a-job)" documentation mentions:

> You can pass variables to a downstream job with [`dotenv` variable inheritance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) and [`needs:project`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsproject).
> These variables are only available in the script of the job and can’t be used to configure it, for example, with `rules` or `artifact:paths`.

Except `needs:project` is marked as a feature for GitLab Premium only.
See [issue 14311](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14311#note_235671733):

> Because multi-project pipelines is a GitLab Premium feature (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html) this feature should be as well.
> For those who may be disappointed, I apologize.

There was a [proposal to move multi-project-pipeline to the Community Edition](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29626): denied.

Comment: Updated documentation: [`artifacts:reports:dotenv`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv)

Comment: Does this work if you want to pass a variable instead of a file?

Comment: @tzg It should, with [`artifacts:reports:dotenv`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv).

Answer (score 11):

You can use artifacts for passing data between jobs. Here's example from [Flant](https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/332842/) to check previous pipeline manual decision:

```
approve:
  script:
    - mkdir -p .ci_status
    - echo $(date +%s) > .ci_status/approved
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .ci_status/

NOT approve:
  script:
    - mkdir -p .ci_status
    - echo $(date +%s) > .ci_status/not_approved
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .ci_status/

deploy to production:
  script:
    - if [[ $(cat .ci_status/not_approved) > $(cat .ci_status/approved) ]]; then echo "Need approve from release engineer!"; exit 1; fi
    - echo "deploy to production!"
```

Comment: Thanks. This assumes that all jobs run on the same server / under the same runner.

Comment: Generally, yes. But you can specify path for shared mount for all runners from host. And path at host itself can be mounted from somewhere :)

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks. With many jobs these paths would need to be well organized as to not collide but I suppose this is outside of the scope of the question. That said, it would result in a giant & fragile mess of a state saved on the file system. Ideally I would want Gitlab to handle in a clean and robust way like git or a DBMS - I don't need to know much about how either is implemented to use them.

Comment: I cannot pass artifacts between successive jobs using different containers. Is this possible with Gitlab-CI?

Comment: @PaulRougieux yep, but it reqires to mount shared volume between jobs. Where you need to mount depends where is your artifacts are. In gitlab-runner container (which executes commands you defined in gitlab-ci.yml) or in your container, where all magic goes. Second is straight forward - you control it. First is tricky - you need define this volume in config.toml for all runners. Beware of concequences.

Answer (score 2):

There's an open [issue 47517 'Pass variables between jobs'](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/47517) on Gitlab CE..

> CI/CD often needs to pass information from one job to another and
>   artifacts can be used for this, although it's a heavy solution with
>   unintended side effects. Workspaces is another proposal for passing
>   files between jobs. But sometimes you don't want to pass files at all,
>   just a small bit of data.

I have faced the same issue, and workaround this by storing DATA in file, then access to it in other Jobs..

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the created file is not found because the directory is changing depending on the job i guess

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: It works using pipeline id instead of time, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of can....The way I went about it:

You can send a POST request to the project to save a variable:

```
export VARIABLE=secret

curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/variables/" --form "key=VARIABLE" --form "value=$VARIABLE"
```

and cleanup after the work/trigger is finished

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.seznam.net/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/variables/VARIABLE"
```

I'm not sure it suppose to be used this way, but it does the trick. You have the variable accessible for all the following jobs (specially when you use `trigger` and `script` in that job is not an option.)

Just please make sure, you run the cleanup job even if previous once fail...