# Passing files from a rocker container to a latex container within a gitlab-ci job

Tags: r, gitlab, latex, gitlab-ci

I would like to use Gitlab CI to compile a Latex article as explained in [this answer on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459564/44254) (a similar pdf generation example is shown in the [gitlab documentation for artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html)). I use a special latex template given by the journal editor. My Latex article contains figures made with the R statistical software. R and Latex are two large software installations with a lot of dependencies so I decided to use two separate containers for the build, one for the statistical analysis and visualization with R and one to compile a Latex document to pdf.

Here is the content of `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
knit_rnw_to_tex:
  image: rocker/verse:4.0.0
  script:
  - Rscript -e "knitr::knit('article.Rnw')"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - figure/

compile_pdf:
  image: aergus/latex
  script:
  - ls figure
  - latexmk -pdf -bibtex -use-make article.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - article.pdf
```

The `knit_rnw_to_tex` job executed in the R "rocker" container is successful and I can download the figure artifacts from the gitlab "jobs" page. The issue in the second job `compile_pdf` is that `ls figure` shows me an empty folder and the Latex article compilation fails because of missing figures.

- It should be possible to use artifacts to pass data between jobs  according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56239978/2641825) and to this [well explained forum post](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/access-artifact-in-next-task-to-deploy/9295/4) but they use only one container for different jobs. It doesn't work in my case. Probably because I use two different containers?
- Another solution would be to use only the rocker/tidyverse container and install latexmk in there, but the installation of `apt install latexmk` fails for an unknown reason. Maybe because It has over hundred dependencies and that is to much for gitlab-CI?
- The "[dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies)" keyword could help according to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38155856/2641825), but the artifacts are still not available when I use it.
- How can I pass the artifacts from one job to the other?
- Should I use cache as explained in [docs.gitlab.com / caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/)?

Comment: You have it separated as two separate project builds or it is one project and two stages?

Comment: One project and two stages as visible in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Maybe I should make a simple reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the comment as I wanted to be sure, how you do it.  Example would help too, but I'll be generic for now (using `docker`).

To run multiple containers you need a
[(`The Docker executor`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html))

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) on it:

> The Docker executor when used with GitLab CI, connects to Docker
> Engine and runs each build in a separate and isolated container using
> the predefined image that is set up in `.gitlab-ci.yml` and in
> accordance in `config.toml`.

### Workflow

> The Docker executor divides the job into multiple steps:
>
> - Prepare: Create and start the services.
> - Pre-job: Clone, restore cache and download artifacts from previous stages. This is run on a special Docker image.
> - Job: User build. This is run on the user-provided Docker image.
> - Post-job: Create cache, upload artifacts to GitLab. This is run on a special Docker Image.

Your `config.toml` could look like this:

```
[runners.docker]
  image = "rocker/verse:4.0.0"
  builds_dir = /home/builds/rocker

[[runners.docker.services]]
  name = "aergus/latex"
  alias = "latex"
```

From above linked documentation:

### The `image` keyword

The `image` keyword is the name of the Docker image that is present in the local Docker Engine (list all images with docker images) or any image that can be found at Docker Hub. For more information about images and Docker Hub please read the Docker Fundamentals documentation.

In short, with image we refer to the Docker image, which will be used to create a container on which your build will run.

If you don’t specify the `namespace`, Docker implies library which includes all official images. That’s why you’ll see many times the library part omitted in .gitlab-ci.yml and config.toml. For example you can define an image like `image: ruby:2.6`, which is a shortcut for image: `library/ruby:2.6`.

Then, for each Docker image there are tags, denoting the version of the image. These are defined with a colon (:) after the image name. For example, for Ruby you can see the supported tags at [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/). If you don’t specify a tag (like `image: ruby`), latest is implied.

The `image` you choose to run your build in via `image` directive must have a working shell in its operating system `PATH`. Supported shells are `sh`, `bash`, and `pwsh` (since 13.9) for Linux, and PowerShell for Windows. GitLab Runner cannot execute a command using the underlying OS system calls (such as exec).

### The `services` keyword

The `services` keyword defines just another Docker image that is run during your build and is linked to the Docker image that the image keyword defines. This allows you to access the service image during build time.

The `service` image can run any application, but the most common use case is to run a database container, e.g., `mysql`. It’s easier and faster to use an existing image and run it as an additional container than install `mysql` every time the project is built.

You can see some widely used services examples in the relevant documentation of [CI services examples](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/doc/ci/services/index.md).

If needed, you can assign an `alias` to each service.

### As for your questions:

> It should be possible to use artifacts to pass data between jobs
> according to this answer and to this well explained forum post but
> they use only one container for different jobs. It doesn't work in my
> case. Probably because I use two different containers?

### The builds and cache storage (from documentation)

The Docker executor by default stores all builds in `/builds/<namespace>/<project-name>` and all caches in `/cache` (inside the container). You can overwrite the `/builds` and `/cache` directories by defining the `builds_dir` and `cache_dir` options under the `[[runners]]` section in `config.toml`. This will modify where the data are stored inside the container.

If you modify the `/cache` storage path, you also need to make sure to mark this directory as persistent by defining it in `volumes = ["/my/cache/"]` under the `[runners.docker]` section in `config.toml`.

- `builds_dir` -> Absolute path to a directory where builds are stored in the context of the selected executor. For example, locally, Docker, or SSH.

[The [[runners]] section documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section)

As you may have noticed I have customized the `build_dir` in your `toml` file to `/home/builds/rocker`, please adjust it to your own path.

> How can I pass the artifacts from one job to the other?

You can use the `build_dir` directive. Second option would to use [Job Artifacts API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts).

> Should I use cache as explained in docs.gitlab.com / caching?

Yes, You should use `cache` to store project dependencies.  The advantage is that you fetch the dependencies only once from internet and then subsequent runs are much faster as they can skip this step.  `Artifacts` are used to share results between build stages.

I hope it is now clearer and I have pointed you into right direction.

Comment: Thank you, the `services` keyword sounds like it could be useful. I want the latex container to provide the service of compiling the Latex document. Just have to figure out how to send the `latexmk` command to that service.

Comment: @PaulRougieux You could so it quite simple.  Set a `command` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` like: 

`services:
  - name: aergus/latex
    command: ["/usr/bin/latexmk", "run"]`

Comment: Thanks, but I then need to send data to that service. Sorry networking between Docker containers remains confusing to me. I'm very busy now but I will try to make a reproducible example before the end of this week.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Been there so I totally understand that.  Take your time.

Answer (score 2):

The two different images are not the cause of your problems. The artifacts are saved in one image (which seems to work), and then restored in the other. I would therefore advise against building (and maintaining) a single image, as that should not be necessary here.

The reason you are having problems is that you are missing build stages which inform gitlab about dependencies between the jobs. I would therefore advise you to specify stages as well as their respective jobs in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - do_stats
  - do_compile_pdf

knit_rnw_to_tex:
  stage: do_stats
  image: rocker/verse:4.0.0
  script:
  - Rscript -e "knitr::knit('article.Rnw')"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - figure/

compile_pdf:
  stage: do_compile_pdf
  image: aergus/latex
  script:
  - ls figure
  - latexmk -pdf -bibtex -use-make article.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - article.pdf
```

### Context:

By default, all artifacts of previous build stages are made available in later stages *if you add the corresponding specifications*.

If  you do not specify any stages, gitlab will put all jobs into the default `test` stage and execute them in parallel, assuming that they are independent and do not require each others artifacts. It will still store the artifacts but not make them available between the jobs. This is presumably what is causing your problems.

As for the `cache`: Artifacts are how you pass files between build stages. Caches are for well, caching. In practice, they are used for things like external packages in order to avoid having to download them multiple times, [see here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/). Caches are somewhat unpredictable in situations with multiple different runners. They are only used for performance reasons, and passing files between jobs using `cache` rather than using the artifact system is a huge anti-pattern.

Edit: I don't know precisely what your `knitr` setup is, but if you generate an `article.tex` from your `article.Rnw`, then you probably need to add that to your `artifacts` as well.

Also, `services` are used for things like a MySQL server for testing databases, or the dind (docker in docker) daemon to build docker images. This should not be necessary in your case. Similarly, you should *not* need to change any runner configuration (in their respective `config.toml`) from the defaults.

Edit2: I added a MWE [here](https://github.com/hfhc2/stat-example), which works with my gitlab setup.